# Did a SQL Server instance ever participate in replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

How can I tell whether a SQL Server instance ever had replication in use or not? I'm debugging an issue with a 3rd party software. This software (Red Gate SQL Backup) reports the distribution database to be missing. The company has asked to find out whether this server has ever used replication or not. How can I find out?

Replication does not seem to be installed and the distribution database is not present. None of the databases use replication.

Comment: My guess is the software is looking for a check to see if there is a common indicator for replication that pops.  For instance, maybe it is testing the `Replication XPs` server configuration option to see if it is turned on.  Ultimately, your best bet would be to reach out to the vendor and just ask them what their software does to check for repl.  Likewise, you could also run a trace/XEvents session to see everything that the software is doing on the instance and paint the picture for yourself there.

Comment: I would ask RedGate that question. There are various places items could get left on a server that it might pickup as replication being used (e.g. replication tables in msdb or user databases, replication directories on the server itself, orphaned registry keys).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'll be able to reliable tell if the server has ever used replication or not.  For example, if someone drops replication properly, there will be no trace left behind.

Answer (score -1):

Please check

```
select * from sys.servers;
```

Check these column values.

```
is_publisher
is_subscriber
is_distributor
is_nonsql_subscriber
```

Comment: Nope, I recently removed replication from our production server (about 3 weeks ago), this method doesn't work and shows no trace that our server was once configured for replication.